# I'm getting a 1004 error when I try to use the LastRow variable to copy and paste data

Tags: excel, vba

Thanks in advance for your help. The question I have is really about the 1004 error that I'm getting around the LastRow variable that I am trying to use. But I will do my best to explain everything.

The code that I have:

-First looks in a specific Windows folder and opens the most recently updated file in that folder and opens it.

-The code then looks in a specific Outlook folder and opens the most email based on whether or not that email has an attachment.

-The email attachment is extracted, saved in a folder, and opened.

-At this point there should be 2 files open: the one from the email and the file that was opened from the Windows folder.

-What I am trying to do is copy data from one file into the other and I'm trying to use the LastRow variable to do that. In the code below, everything runs fine until I get to the line that says `ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AB" & SixTimesLastRow).Copy`

```
    Const olFolderInbox As Integer = 6
    '~~> Path for the attachment
    Const AttachmentPath As String = "C:\Users\DJ.Oliver\Documents\Test"
    Option Explicit
    Sub UpdateBusinessJustification()

    Dim oOlAp As Object, oOlns As Object, oOlInb As Object, CABLastRow As Long, 
    SixTimesLastRow As Long, objDoc As Object, objWord As Object, objSelection 
    As Object, nonProdCount As Integer, nonProdDT As Integer
    Dim oOlItm As Object, oOlAtch As Object, fname As String, sFound As String, 
    totalRowCount As Integer, wFound As String, wdRange As Word.Range, str As 
    String, nonProdCopyToWord As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook, uRng As Range, tbl As Table, ProdCount As Integer, 
    ProdDT As Integer, myDate As Date, tableCount As Integer, MyPath As String, 
    MyFile As String, LatestFile As String
    Dim LatestDate As Date, LMD As Date, CABPath As String, r As Range, x As 
    Variant, CopyCRRange As Range


    MyPath = "C:\Users\User\Documents\Reports\"
    CABPath = "C:\Users\User\Documents"


    MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "\CAB*.xlsx", vbNormal)

    If Len(MyFile) = 0 Then

        MsgBox "No files were found…", vbExclamation

        Exit Sub

    End If

    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0

        LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)

        If LMD > LatestDate Then

            LatestFile = MyFile

            LatestDate = LMD

        End If

        MyFile = Dir

    Loop

    'Open the latest CAB file

    Workbooks.Open MyPath & LatestFile

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.AutoFilterMode Then
            ws.AutoFilterMode = False
        End If
    Next ws


    '~~> New File Name for the attachment
    Dim NewFileName As String
    NewFileName = "MorningOps " & Format(Date, "MM-DD-YYYY")
    '~~> Get Outlook instance
    Set oOlAp = GetObject(, "Outlook.application")
    Set oOlns = oOlAp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oOlInb = oOlns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Daily CAB Reports")


    '~~> Check if there are any actual unread emails
    If oOlInb.Items.Restrict("[UnRead] = True").Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "NO Unread Email In Inbox"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    '~~> Extract the attachment from the 1st unread email
    For Each oOlItm In oOlInb.Items.Restrict("[UnRead] = True")
        '~~> Check if the email actually has an attachment
        If oOlItm.Attachments.Count <> 0 Then
            For Each oOlAtch In oOlItm.Attachments
                '~~> Download the attachment
                oOlAtch.SaveAsFile NewFileName & oOlAtch.Filename
                Exit For
            Next
        Else
            MsgBox "The First item doesn't have an attachment"
        End If
        Exit For
    Next

    '~~> Mark 1st unread email as read
    For Each oOlItm In oOlInb.Items.Restrict("[UnRead] = True")
        oOlItm.UnRead = False
        DoEvents
        oOlItm.Save
        Exit For
        Next

    '--> Search for downloaded file and open without knowing exact filename
    sFound = Dir(CABPath & "\*Data Center CAB*.xlsx")
    If sFound <> "" Then
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=sFound
    End If

    'Set uRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A2")

    '--> Set variable for last row in sheet containing data

    Workbooks(LatestFile).Activate
    CABLastRow = Sheets("CAB").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'Activate the latest CAB file and flear the contents
    'Workbooks(LatestFile).Activate
    Worksheets("CAB").Range("$A$1:$AB" & CABLastRow).ClearContents

    'Activate the 6x report and apply the filter to look for next week's changes
    Workbooks(sFound).Activate
    SixTimesLastRow = Sheets("Combined CAB Agenda").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AB" & SixTimesLastRow).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
        xlFilterNextWeek, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic

    'Copy next week changes from 6x daily report to CAB report
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AB" & SixTimesLastRow).Copy


End Sub
```

Comment: Quick test, add `Debug.Print SixTimeLastRow` right before the `.Copy` line and see what the Immediate Window outputs.  Also, try switching `ActiveSheet` to the sheet name itself, i.e. `Sheets("Sheet1").Range(...`.

Comment: I added the Debug line right before the .Copy line and oddly enough, nothing printed. The code just returned the same 1004 error as before.

Comment: look at how you're setting the `SixTimesLastRow` variable. If the debug print is showing nothing, that variable isn't being set correctly. Step through with `F8` and when you get to that line see if you can determine why it's not being set correctly. Try also adding the workbook before the worksheet too, just to make sure it is looking to the correct sheet.